# SPFX modern page remove edit page button

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, modern-pages

is there a way to hide edit page button and replace it with another icon link to say unable to edit until page is approved? idea is to remove the edit button so users cannot edit until the page has been approved or rejected.

i was looking at spfx extensions however i was not able to find anything related to pages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could deploy the SPFX: [react-application-injectcss](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-application-injectcss)

Then inject a custom Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) on modern pages to hide the Edit button.